# Cannot send file with Popen.communicate "<(echo ..." File is not accessible: `/dev/fd/62'

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I'm trying to send files via command line (this works in Mac and in ubuntu server machines) but for some reason, in the production server I'm getting an error

```
 cmd_list = [
        'blastn',
        '-query',"<(echo -e \">{}\\n{}\")".format('seq', seq),
        '-subject',"<(echo -e \">{}\\n{}\")".format('sec_rc', seq_rc),
        '-reward','2',
        '-max_target_seqs','1',
        '-penalty','-4',
        '-word_size','7',#'-ungapped',
        '-evalue','1','-strand',"plus",
        #'-soft_masking','false' ,'-dust','no',
        '-outfmt',"'6 sstart send qstart qend score length mismatch gaps gapopen nident'"]
        cmd = " ".join(cmd_list)
        p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
        out,err = p.communicate()
```

This is the error I'm getting and I have no idea what is it about

```
Command line argument error: Argument "subject". File is not accessible:  `/dev/fd/62'
```

This is my production machine

```
 lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Have you considered doing it in a shell-independent manner?

Comment: you mean using files? I have but apparently it takes longer to process

Comment: You're actually better off not using a list and passing an explicit string here, btw. The point of passing a list is that you have an argv that's going to be parsed exactly as given, but when you join it with spaces, you completely throw away that benefit -- so this code **looks** like it has safety features in scenarios where it doesn't, at all.

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming that by "takes longer to process" you're referring to the lack of parallelism?  That can be worked around using explicitly configured FIFOs. There aren't enough details in this question right now to allow a good answer, though -- could you edit to let us see what `cmd` is supposed to come out looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is needlessly buggy and insecure ("insecure" because you're having arguments, which would otherwise be data, concatenated into a string which is parsed as code). **Don't use a shell here.** Instead, have the Python interpreter do the same job you'd otherwise be asking a shell to do but with explicit named FIFOs.

```
import subprocess, tempfile, threading, os

def writeToFifo(filename, content):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)

redirect_cmd = ['bash', '-c', 'exec >"$1"; shift; exec "$@"', "_"]

fifo_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    query_fifo = os.path.join(fifo_dir, 'query_fifo')
    subject_fifo = os.path.join(fifo_dir, 'subject_fifo')
    os.mkfifo(query_fifo)
    os.mkfifo(subject_fifo)

    query_thread = threading.Thread(target=writeToFifo, args=(query_fifo, seq))
    subject_thread = threading.Thread(target=writeToFifo, args=(subject_fifo, seq))

    cmd_list = [
        'blastn',
        '-query', query_fifo,
        '-subject', subject_fifo,
        '-reward','2',
        '-max_target_seqs','1',
        '-penalty','-4',
        '-word_size','7',#'-ungapped',
        '-evalue','1','-strand',"plus",
        #'-soft_masking','false' ,'-dust','no',
        '-outfmt','6 sstart send qstart qend score length mismatch gaps gapopen nident'
    ]

    query_thread.start()
    subject_thread.start()
    p = Popen(cmd_list, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out,err = p.communicate()
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(fifo_dir)
```

Comment: the code hangs in this part     query_proc = subprocess.Popen(['seq', seq], stdout=open(query_fifo, 'w'))

Comment: @user1532587, ahh -- oops; need to move the open into the subprocess. Easily done, edit upcoming.

Comment: @user1532587, ...done; the FIFOs are now opened in the subprocess, which does not block the parent.

Comment: seems nice, anyway I get _: line 0: exec: sec_rc: not found (the variable is defined)

Comment: @user1532587, yes, that's assuming `sec_rc` is a program you're running with the Python variable named `seq_rc` containing an argument to pass it to generate the content which should be readable via the file name passed to `-subject`; if there exists no `sec_rc` program it'll fail for the obvious reason. Replace appropriately for whatever you're actually trying to do, which I've been unable to deduce from the question.

Comment: what I have in -subject is a file generated by biopython: 
`record_s = SeqRecord(Seq(seq_rc), id = record_id + "_rc")` I still don't know how to put the content in there using Popen

Comment: I've also tried to write this way SeqIO.write(record_q, query_fifo, "fasta"), but the codes hangs

Comment: I don't know BioPython, so the code in your comment doesn't mean anything to me. Are you trying to stream a string? (How large of one? Absent some very specific circumstances, I don't much believe the "apparently it takes longer to process").

Comment: is just writing the content into the file, how can I do that using your example? the part that has the redirect

Comment: So you just have a precalculated string, and one short enough to fit onto a command-line argument? There's no point to using process substitution to write a string. Any string so short it's allowed on a command-line argument will take almost no time to just write to a regular file instead.

Comment: I've edited to assume that `seq` and `seq_rc` are just strings you want written to the FIFOs, but... it's a silly thing to try to do in the first place.

Comment: well it could be the case that the file is being written in a thread and the blast command start before the thread finishes. So I think the file writing should be blocking the main thread

Comment: @user1532587, here's the thing, though -- it's faster to read from a regular file than to read from a FIFO. And if your file were too long, you couldn't pass it on a command-line argument at all; it would be over the length limit. So if you have a short file (under 1MB, say), your best bet is just to write it straight to disk.

Comment: @user1532587, ...I don't know what you mean wrt. "the file writing should be blocking the main thread". Do you mean it would do that if you didn't take this approach? Yes, it would, but unless this is a really large file, *it's probably still faster that way even so*.